# Logic error AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sdk

```html
package com.karanvir.tip;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static com.karanvir.tip.R.drawable.p;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public EditText people;

    public EditText amount;
    public EditText percentage;
    public EditText finalAmount;
    public String finalAmountz;
    public RatingBar rating;
    public TextView txt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

         people=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        amount=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
         percentage=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
         finalAmount=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
        rating=(RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
                //ratingBar.setRating(3);
        txt=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void calc(View view){

        try{
            double pep= Double.parseDouble(people.getText().toString());
            double a=Double.parseDouble(amount.getText().toString());
            double perc=Double.parseDouble(percentage.getText().toString());
            double percc=Double.parseDouble(percentage.getText().toString());


            if(pep>1||pep==1){
                if(perc>1.0) {
                    double aa=a;
                    perc = perc / 100;
                    a = (a * perc);
                    double newamount=a+aa;
                    double placeholder = newamount / pep;
                    double rounder = Math.round(placeholder);


                    finalAmountz = "$" + String.valueOf(rounder);
                    finalAmount.setText(finalAmountz.toString());

                    if (perc>0.12) {
                        rating.setRating(5);
                        rating.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    else if (perc>0.10&&perc<0.12||perc==0.10) {
                        rating.setRating(4);
                        rating.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                   else if (perc>0.7&&perc<0.10||perc==0.07) {
                        rating.setRating(3);
                        rating.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                   else if (perc>0.05&&perc<0.07||perc==0.05) {
                        rating.setRating(2);
                        rating.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    if (perc<0.05) {
                        rating.setRating(1);
                        rating.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }


                }



            }
            else if (pep<1||pep==1){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Enter 1 person minimum", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }


    }
}
```

Please don't rip me apart here. But I'm new to android development. I'm making a tip calculator app right now, everything works the way I want it to. However, my star Calculation is off. it keeps showing 1 star? Please look at lines 72-117. Can someone help me? Sorry for the noob question, I'm still learning.

```html
package com.karanvir.tip;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static com.karanvir.tip.R.drawable.p;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public EditText people;

    public EditText amount;
    public EditText percentage;
    public EditText finalAmount;
    public String finalAmountz;
    public RatingBar rating;
    public TextView txt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

         people=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        amount=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
         percentage=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
         finalAmount=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
        rating=(RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
                //ratingBar.setRating(3);
        txt=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void calc(View view){

        try{
            double pep= Double.parseDouble(people.getText().toString());
            double a=Double.parseDouble(amount.getText().toString());
            double perc=Double.parseDouble(percentage.getText().toString());


            if(pep>1||pep==1){
                if(perc>1.0) {
                    double aa=a;
                    perc = perc / 100;
                    a = (a * perc);
                    double newamount=a+aa;
                    double placeholder = newamount / pep;
                    double rounder = Math.round(placeholder);


                    finalAmountz = "$" + String.valueOf(rounder);
                    finalAmount.setText(finalAmountz.toString());

                    if (perc>12) {
                        rating.setRating(5);
                        rating.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    if (perc>10&&perc<12||perc==10) {
                        rating.setRating(4);
                        rating.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    if (perc>7&&perc<10||perc==7) {
                        rating.setRating(3);
                        rating.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    if (perc>5&&perc<7||perc==5) {
                        rating.setRating(2);
                        rating.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    if (perc<5) {
                        rating.setRating(1);
                        rating.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }


                }
                else if(perc<=1.0){
                    double aa=a;
                    a = (a * perc);
                    double newamount=a+aa;
                    double placeholder = newamount / pep;
                    double rounder = Math.round(placeholder);
                    finalAmountz = "$" + String.valueOf(rounder);
                    finalAmount.setText(finalAmountz.toString());



                    finalAmountz = "$" + String.valueOf(rounder);
                    finalAmount.setText(finalAmountz.toString());
                    if (perc>12)
                        rating.setRating(5);
                    rating.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    if (perc>10&&perc<12||perc==10)
                        rating.setRating(4);
                    rating.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    if (perc>7&&perc<10||perc==7)
                        rating.setRating(3);
                    rating.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    if (perc>5&&perc<7||perc==5)
                        rating.setRating(2);
                    rating.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    if (perc<5)
                        rating.setRating(1);
                    rating.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                }


            }
            else if (pep>1){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Enter 1 person minamum", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean with "it keeps showing 1 star"? could you provide a screenshot of the result and describe the expected result?

Comment: So what happens is when I click to see my results, it shows only 1 star . It should only show one star if percantage is less than 5

Comment: I think you have an issue here `else if(perc<=1.0){` because inside this you keep validating perc as being superior to 1. Also you are repeating `rating.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

Comment: It didnt work, I just deleted that line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dividing perc by 100

```
if(pep>1||pep==1){
    if(perc>1.0) {
         double aa=a;
         perc = perc / 100;
 ....
```

Unless the value you input is superior to **500** then its value will always be inferior to 5 (your last condition) and therefore always give 1 star

Comment: thanks for the tip, next time ill be sure to double check all my refernces or adjustments to the variable im referring to later!

Comment: No problem. Glad to help

Comment: It all depends on the values you are inserting. You need to check what value arrives to the conditions. My answer is still \correct

Comment: im inserting values like 12 for example, now nothing? 12/100 should be  0.12. yet these conditions still dont work in my statements. im so confused